# AWS Boto3 upload files issue

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I am facing a weird issue.

I am trying to upload few parquet files from local PC to S3 bucket. Below is the script I used.
It ran well for the first file , but as soon as I change the folder and try loading a different file to the same s3 bucket. It doesn't load. The code doesn't fail. But the 2nd file is not visible in the s3 bucket. I have no clue why its behaving this way.

```
s3 = boto3.resource('s3', aws_access_key_id='*****', aws_secret_access_key='****')
bucket = s3.Bucket(BUCKET)
bucket.upload_file("****.parquet", "****.parquet")
```

Comment: Can you reproduce that behavior with different files? Otherwise there's nothing we can do here.

Comment: Any error message? How big is the file? By the way, you should not be putting access credentials within your code files. Instead, use the AWS CLI `aws configure` command to store the credentials in a configuration file. You can then just use `s3 = boto3.resource('s3')` without specifying credentials.

Comment: Thanks  @john .Actually the files were not shown on refresh. Once I closed the S3 Browser and opened it .It got reflected in the S3 path.

Comment: FYI, the S3 console caches the list of files. There's a "refresh" button in the S3 console to update the file list.